# How to logout JWT token using Multi authentication with different table of User

Tags: laravel, bearer-token, jwt

Here is a code in config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    'client' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'clients',
    ]
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'clients' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Client::class,
    ],
],
```

My login function doesnt have a problem with this code for different login user :

```
config()->set('auth.defaults.guard', 'client');
Config::set('jwt.user', 'App\Client');
Config::set('auth.providers.clients.model', Client::class);
```

Here is my logout function :

```
function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, ['token' => 'required']);
    Config::set('jwt.user', 'App\Client');
    Config::set('auth.providers.clients.model', Client::class);
    try {
        JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Failed to logout'], 500);
    }
}
```

I'm using Laravel 6 and tymon/jwt-auth "1.0.0-rc.5.1"

Answer (score 2):

If you have one token table for both user and client then you can do like this...For logout you just have to delete the token from token table... Simple way =>

```
public function logOut($id) {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            $user = Auth::user();
            Token::where('user_id',$user->id)
                    ->where(external identification)
                    ->delete();
            $response = [
                    'status' => true,
                    'message' => 'Successfully Logged Out',
            ];
            return response()->json($response); //@ sending response
        } else {
            $response = [
                    'status' => false,
                    'message' => 'Bad Request!',
            ];
            return response()->json($response); //@ sending response
        }                     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it simpler with with the Auth/laravel

```
    public function logoutapp(){
      $user = Auth::user();
      $userid =$user->id;
      DB::table('oauth_access_tokens')->where('user_id', $userid)->update(['revoked' => true]);
    return Response::json(array('succes' => true, 'data' => 'Logout succesfully!'), 200);
}
```