# Laravel passport how to logout user?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I have a main and client projects. The client project uses authorization of the main project through laravel passport.Login works fine, but when I try to log out using `$request->user()->token()->revoke();` the client project redirects the user back to the main project for authorization, but for some reason, instead of asking for login, the main project simply issues a new token and redirects user back to the client project. I think the problem is that my login routes and the routes that returns SPA application are placed in the web, while all other routes are placed in api, but I can't undertand how to fix this. Also, I'm using \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class in web(as I understant in allows me not to send bearer token in every request). What should I do to make logout work properly?

my login and application routes(placed in web)

```
Route::get('/authorization{any}', 'SpaController@auth')->where('any', '^.*$');
Route::get('/{any}', 'SpaController@main')->where('any', '^(?!api)(?!logout)(?!storage).*$')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
```

authorization controller

```
public function login(Login $request)
{
    if (config('recaptcha.enabled') && !$this->checkRecaptcha($request['recaptchaToken'], $request->ip())) {
         return 'Captcha error';
    }
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();
    return (['redirect' => redirect()->intended('/')->getTargetUrl()]);
}
```

logout route(placed in api)

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api','request.log'])->get('/logout', function (Request $request) {
    $request->user()->token()->revoke();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using the logout method connected to the [Auth Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#logging-out)?

In my controller it looks something like this... 
auth()->logout();

Comment: @JohnSims if I use auth()->logout() I receive error Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::logout does not exist

Comment: Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout'); try this

Comment: @TimeParadox I tried to install laravel basic authorization but when I did it auth::attempt started to always return false

Comment: your `oauth_access_token` table is same for both main and client?

Comment: @user11622164 How can I check it? Here is all my oauth related tables https://prnt.sc/sifuez

Comment: @user11622164 seems like I really have different tokens for main and client. How can I make it same for both?

Comment: you have two `oauth_access_token` table?

Comment: @user11622164 no, but in table I there are different tokens for main application and client application. So when user from client app sends his token my app invalidates side app token, but not main app token. Is there any way to invalidate all tokens at once?

Comment: @user11622164 btw, I just set every token "revoked" to 1, and my authorization still works everywhere

Comment: I have written detailed article to loogut a user from all devices - https://emciyevabdulla.medium.com/laravel-passport-logout-auth-user-from-all-devices-super-easy-way-d0638d8a6011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well! i am not sure what you are doing but Hope it will Help you a little bit

If You Have Single `oauth_access_token` for both `main` and `client` and also your both `main` and `client` tables are separate Then you can do like this Simple:

Table Structures:

oauth_access_tokens

```
id             | user_id                      | name
// token        // id from main and client     // use this like boolean 0=> main 1=>client
```

by this you can easily separate the `main` and `client` tokens

Make a Logout Function Like this =>

[How to logout JWT token using Multi authentication with different table of User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61494765/how-to-logout-jwt-token-using-multi-authentication-with-different-table-of-user/61496579#61496579)

If any modification needed let me know!